# Stop sql developer re-opening code editor windows/tabs

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Whenever I open Oracle SQL developer, it re-opens a load of old code editor tabs/windows from a while ago.

despite closing these and exiting, these tabs re-appear every time I open SQL developer and I end up closing them down again.

I have tried the setting

tools > preferences > auto pin code editors as both checked and unchecked and with the 'max number of editors' set to 1  - but this doesn't seem to make the slightest bit of difference.

I just want to start SQL developer with nothing open.

Any idea what settings I use to do this?

Comment: Which version are you seeing that in, and on which platform; and can you try with a later version?  (19.1 is out today!) Just guessing, but it sounds like maybe either it's crashing during shutdown before it can save the current window state/preferences, or the file it's supposed to save the preferences in is read-only for some reason. Are changes you make in the preferences panel retained across restarts?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. Finally the bellow to menu command solved it:
Window/Close All Documents
Windows/Reset Windows To Factory Settings
(I don't know which of them was the relevant.)

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing this issue for few weeks. Windows/"Reset Windows To Factory Settings" has worked for me.

Comment: Please don’t post answers as a way of thanking previous contributors for their answers, or to validate their solutions.